# Why Apache SPA mod_rewrite config uses dot in regex and caret crashes Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

Typical Apache SPA config based on mod_rewrite:

```
DocumentRoot "${webDir}"

<Directory "${webDir}">
  LogLevel rewrite:trace8

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

If I replace last rule's regex with caret:

```
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Apache segfaults on `http://localhost/` (works with any non-empty path). Error log is not suspicious:

```
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493): strip per-dir prefix: /home/user/work/out/ -> 
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493): applying pattern '^' to uri ''
[rewrite:trace4] mod_rewrite.c(493): RewriteCond: input='/home/user/work/out/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] mod_rewrite.c(493): rewrite '' -> 'index.html'
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493): add per-dir prefix: index.html -> /home/user/work/out/index.html
[rewrite:trace2] mod_rewrite.c(493): strip document_root prefix: /home/user/work/out/index.html -> /index.html
[rewrite:trace1] mod_rewrite.c(493): internal redirect with /index.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Log with dot (which doesn't result in crash) is:

```
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493) strip per-dir prefix: /home/user/work/out/ -> 
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493) applying pattern '.' to uri ''
[rewrite:trace1] mod_rewrite.c(493) pass through /home/user/work/out/
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493) strip per-dir prefix: /home/user/work/out/index.html -> index.html
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493) applying pattern '.' to uri 'index.html'
[rewrite:trace4] mod_rewrite.c(493) RewriteCond: input='/home/user/work/out/index.html' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace1] mod_rewrite.c(493) pass through /home/user/work/out/index.html
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using this rule (in what context)? What other directives do you have? From the look of the log entries, this is being used in a _directory_ context. (The log entries appear to be from two different requests?) In which case the rule with a dot does not apply when requesting the root directory. (Aside: ordinarily you shouldn’t need to change the regex to `^` here, since that is the job of mod_dir.)

Comment: @MrWhite You are right, the rewrite settings are in `Directory` context. I updated the question to reflect it. I stripped private paths from log entries, now the request is the same: `http://localhost/`, they differ only by regex. Are you saying that `.` rule is ignored and *mod_dir* searches for `index.html`? Should I debug it with `LogLevel trace8`?